# pgfplotstable: fixed precision, switch-case?

Tags: tables, math-mode, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I tried using `pgfplotstable` to format an external txt file, but some problems arrived. My goal is to show the numbers with fixed, fixed zerofill, precision two and with the presign,
which should result in numbers like -0.30 -0.10 -0.00 +0.00 ...

Additionally I want that the values between -0.05 and 0 are display in red and the values between 0.00 and 0.05 are displayed in green.

Problems:

1) I could not combine the `fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=2` and `pgfplotstabletypeset` 
2) Does some switch-case structure exist for my 3 cases problem?

My try was:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,6pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=0cm,right=1cm,margin=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}

%\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/showpos}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableset{fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=2}

\def\bordervalue{0}
\pgfplotstabletypeset [
assume math mode=false,
postproc cell content/.style={@cell content={
\pgfmathparse{int(less(abs(#1),0.05)) }
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
  \color{red} #1
   \else
       \color{black} #1
    \fi 
  }
  }
]{G.txt}

%\pgfmathparse{int(less(abs(#1),0.05)}% + 2*int(greater(#1,0)) + 1*int(less(#1,0)) }


\end{document}
```

The input file G.txt could be found on http://pastebin.ca/2460404.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to pass the number `#1` through the number formatter `\pgfmathprintnumber` to apply the number formatting styles:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,6pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=0cm,right=1cm,margin=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}

%\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/showpos}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableset{fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=2, print sign}

\def\bordervalue{0}
\pgfplotstabletypeset [
    assume math mode=false,
    postproc cell content/.style={
        @cell content={
            \pgfmathsetmacro\rounded{round(#1*100)/100}
            \pgfmathparse{int(and(\rounded<0,\rounded>-0.05))) }
            \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
                \color{red}
            \else
                \pgfmathparse{int(and(\rounded>0,\rounded<0.05))) }
                \ifnum\pgfmathresult = 1
                    \color{green!80!black} 
                \else
                    \color{black}
                \fi
            \fi 
            \pgfmathprintnumber{#1}
        }
    }
]{
-0.0018097 -0.0011812 -0.0018097 -0.0010777 -0.0011812 -0.00091496 -0.51092 -0.52211 -0.87852 -0.82881 -0.87852 -0.91191 -0.82881 -0.64805 -0.88992 -0.88992 -0.042196 -0.071565 -0.042196 -0.026179 -0.071565 -0.067865 -0.678 -0.678
0.10573 0.15634 0.10573 0.22772 0.15634 0.31295 0.7035 0.78193 0.0084089 0.017384 0.0084089 0.005014 0.017384 0.010876 0.74238 0.6281 0.026579 0.038814 0.026579 0.015059 0.038814 0.013339 0.65286 0.52211
-0.0011786 -0.0012848 -0.0011786 -0.0012504 -0.0012848 -0.001648 -0.42615 -0.42615 -0.71871 -0.66541 -0.71871 -0.96146 -0.66541 -0.86645 -0.87627 -0.94483 -0.025052 -0.0088259 -0.025052 -0.011217 -0.0088259 -0.0039391 -0.71638 -0.7035
-0.059451 -0.014264 -0.059451 -0.027808 -0.014264 -0.011648 -0.7035 -0.79525 0.66665 0.48597 0.66665 0.62844 0.48597 0.38709 0.93107 0.9862 -0.29718 -0.45641 -0.29718 -0.10615 -0.45641 -0.17087 -0.76868 -0.71638
-0.17682 -0.26909 -0.17682 -0.28599 -0.26909 -0.29047 -0.80863 -0.86265 0.66592 0.37404 0.66592 0.96741 0.37404 0.77312 0.9724 0.95861 -0.45022 -0.54809 -0.45022 -0.3407 -0.54809 -0.44201 -0.87627 -0.83554
-0.27381 -0.27964 -0.27381 -0.30923 -0.27964 -0.29047 -0.7035 -0.6907 0.31987 0.34877 0.31987 0.67737 0.34877 0.38709 0.79525 0.71638 0.62264 0.61389 0.62264 0.50833 0.61389 0.32461 0.9724 0.93107
-0.0020869 -0.0015176 -0.0020869 -0.0010551 -0.0015176 -0.0010854 -0.54485 -0.54485 -0.92052 -0.90438 -0.92052 -0.84851 -0.90438 -0.81014 -0.95861 -0.91733 -0.030191 -0.043581 -0.030191 -0.028369 -0.043581 -0.036602 -0.59175 -0.54485
0.13569 0.1785 0.13569 0.23582 0.1785 0.42788 0.72934 0.76868 0.0044837 0.0082236 0.0044837 0.00087211 0.0082236 0.0019403 0.6281 0.7555 0.037292 0.060937 0.037292 0.032045 0.060937 0.067865 0.64043 0.59175
-0.0026424 -0.0039391 -0.0026424 -0.0024962 -0.0039391 -0.0022795 -0.43627 -0.46747 -0.90346 -0.92344 -0.90346 -0.80169 -0.92344 -0.68296 -0.87627 -0.9724 -0.038502 -0.015244 -0.038502 -0.02643 -0.015244 -0.013339 -0.7035 -0.72934
-0.071192 -0.01855 -0.071192 -0.046342 -0.01855 -0.023924 -0.74238 -0.80863 0.81428 0.51655 0.81428 0.80164 0.51655 0.51655 1 0.91733 -0.35185 -0.42788 -0.35185 -0.13057 -0.42788 -0.14944 -0.79525 -0.7035
-0.21907 -0.27964 -0.21907 -0.28841 -0.27964 -0.32461 -0.87627 -0.93107 0.78079 0.38709 0.78079 0.866 0.38709 0.96168 0.9862 1 -0.51051 -0.58055 -0.51051 -0.46502 -0.58055 -0.44201 -0.94483 -0.78193
-0.1654 -0.10747 -0.1654 -0.20007 -0.10747 -0.17087 -0.6907 -0.82206 0.34124 0.37404 0.34124 0.81274 0.37404 0.56421 0.83554 0.88992 0.66594 0.61389 0.66594 0.7408 0.61389 0.59712 0.91733 0.9862
-0.031537 -0.048833 -0.031537 -0.078951 -0.048833 -0.083666 -0.86265 -0.86265 -0.61765 -0.58055 -0.61765 -0.45437 -0.58055 -0.56421 -0.95861 -0.95861 -0.0048777 -0.0082236 -0.0048777 -0.017209 -0.0082236 -0.025462 -0.72934 -0.82206
0.29324 0.77312 0.29324 0.32582 0.77312 0.94254 0.88992 0.79525 0.2347 0.48597 0.2347 0.24536 0.48597 0.21156 0.78193 0.6281 0.2146 0.73661 0.2146 0.36213 0.73661 0.63087 0.88992 0.91733
-0.13389 -0.14944 -0.13389 -0.1415 -0.14944 -0.11282 -0.88992 -0.87627 -0.20703 -0.1785 -0.20703 -0.15445 -0.1785 -0.13013 -0.78193 -0.90361 -0.0045587 -0.0045833 -0.0045587 -0.020611 -0.0045833 -0.01855 -0.76868 -0.6907
-0.67341 -0.94254 -0.67341 -0.42991 -0.94254 -0.54809 -0.9724 -1 0.26752 0.34877 0.26752 0.78173 0.34877 0.92344 0.65286 0.66538 0.74124 0.50114 0.74124 0.6664 0.50114 0.71857 0.91733 0.9862
-0.73084 -0.75479 -0.73084 -0.66805 -0.75479 -0.82881 -0.94483 -0.9862 0.6455 0.64805 0.6455 0.7843 0.64805 0.81014 0.95861 1 -0.77703 -0.98083 -0.77703 -0.66586 -0.98083 -0.68296 -1 -0.91733
0.51327 0.66541 0.51327 0.82658 0.66541 0.86645 0.87627 0.88992 0.078642 0.10747 0.078642 0.20046 0.10747 0.24883 0.76868 0.83554 0.025088 0.019784 0.025088 0.017402 0.019784 0.011648 0.78193 0.80863
-0.026796 -0.051652 -0.026796 -0.047092 -0.051652 -0.083666 -0.80863 -0.83554 -0.53344 -0.48597 -0.53344 -0.68384 -0.48597 -0.70068 -0.84907 -0.95861 -0.0038712 -0.0045833 -0.0038712 -0.011216 -0.0045833 -0.016283 -0.71638 -0.71638
0.2732 0.79157 0.2732 0.34948 0.79157 0.81014 0.88992 0.79525 0.19505 0.29047 0.19505 0.17224 0.29047 0.21156 0.84907 0.64043 0.23878 0.73661 0.23878 0.28644 0.73661 0.98083 0.80863 0.91733
-0.15657 -0.1785 -0.15657 -0.12182 -0.1785 -0.097373 -0.80863 -0.7555 -0.18432 -0.17087 -0.18432 -0.40783 -0.17087 -0.31295 -0.80863 -0.91733 -0.008637 -0.013339 -0.008637 -0.032458 -0.013339 -0.019784 -0.7035 -0.57985
-0.65102 -0.81014 -0.65102 -0.37914 -0.81014 -0.56421 -1 -0.9862 0.3467 0.45641 0.3467 0.91552 0.45641 0.96168 0.7555 0.678 0.94019 0.68296 0.94019 0.31416 0.68296 0.31295 0.9724 0.94483
-0.63029 -0.92344 -0.63029 -0.45744 -0.92344 -0.90438 -0.94483 -0.94483 0.9144 0.82881 0.9144 0.94895 0.82881 0.92344 0.9862 1 -0.72363 -0.79157 -0.72363 -0.73496 -0.79157 -0.88538 -0.9862 -0.91733
0.35839 0.38709 0.35839 0.441 0.38709 0.44201 0.84907 0.9724 0.15475 0.11838 0.15475 0.28461 0.11838 0.26909 0.82206 0.72934 0.06664 0.071565 0.06664 0.034815 0.071565 0.034498 0.79525 0.94483
-0.22446 -0.16348 -0.22446 -0.21779 -0.16348 -0.13634 -0.79525 -0.88992 -0.83319 -0.96168 -0.83319 -0.90754 -0.96168 -0.71857 -0.93107 -0.9862 -0.38549 -0.42788 -0.38549 -0.60397 -0.42788 -0.48597 -0.83554 -0.93107
0.12763 0.24883 0.12763 0.14444 0.24883 0.14944 0.78193 0.72934 0.023762 0.022467 0.023762 0.026003 0.022467 0.041139 0.52211 0.49987 0.047699 0.043581 0.047699 0.042619 0.043581 0.021088 0.66538 0.61588
-0.11602 -0.10232 -0.11602 -0.17939 -0.10232 -0.14278 -0.60376 -0.66538 -0.48431 -0.82881 -0.48431 -0.50011 -0.82881 -0.75479 -0.88992 -0.84907 -0.17864 -0.31295 -0.17864 -0.17241 -0.31295 -0.33655 -0.83554 -0.91733
0.25568 0.32461 0.25568 0.28978 0.32461 0.47106 0.80863 0.57985 0.031043 0.027084 0.031043 0.048397 0.027084 0.032498 0.86265 0.91733 0.060971 0.051652 0.060971 0.11495 0.051652 0.083666 0.78193 0.82206
0.24737 0.22047 0.24737 0.21919 0.22047 0.15634 0.87627 0.87627 0.071368 0.036602 0.071368 0.11811 0.036602 0.028795 0.79525 0.82206 0.060089 0.032498 0.060089 0.064756 0.032498 0.023924 0.71638 0.72934
-0.22027 -0.22965 -0.22027 -0.29588 -0.22965 -0.18638 -0.90361 -0.86265 -0.71028 -0.75479 -0.71028 -0.96628 -0.75479 -0.94254 -1 -0.88992 -0.5916 -0.56421 -0.5916 -0.95429 -0.56421 -0.86645 -0.9724 -0.9724
-0.21046 -0.21156 -0.21046 -0.18122 -0.21156 -0.11838 -0.87627 -0.78193 -0.73873 -0.96168 -0.73873 -0.93532 -0.96168 -0.73661 -0.95861 -0.9724 -0.38753 -0.50114 -0.38753 -0.57113 -0.50114 -0.45641 -0.88992 -1
0.12481 0.21156 0.12481 0.16317 0.21156 0.22047 0.83554 0.76868 0.018815 0.023924 0.018815 0.011587 0.023924 0.0076583 0.5564 0.57985 0.044549 0.041139 0.044549 0.071952 0.041139 0.097373 0.6907 0.65286
-0.12249 -0.14278 -0.12249 -0.30033 -0.14278 -0.31295 -0.74238 -0.72934 -0.44067 -0.88538 -0.44067 -0.38896 -0.88538 -0.70068 -0.90361 -0.88992 -0.15526 -0.18638 -0.15526 -0.17976 -0.18638 -0.30157 -0.79525 -0.82206
0.29449 0.37404 0.29449 0.47482 0.37404 0.51655 0.76868 0.59175 0.046439 0.038814 0.046439 0.050236 0.038814 0.048833 0.80863 0.87627 0.070619 0.057699 0.070619 0.13128 0.057699 0.11838 0.7555 0.71638
0.23636 0.24883 0.23636 0.2803 0.24883 0.24883 0.90361 1 0.066555 0.028795 0.066555 0.12315 0.028795 0.083666 0.76868 0.65286 0.04929 0.048833 0.04929 0.098629 0.048833 0.036602 0.72934 0.82206
-0.13027 -0.11838 -0.13027 -0.24623 -0.11838 -0.10232 -0.80863 -0.93107 -0.60727 -0.38709 -0.60727 -0.61205 -0.38709 -0.36127 -0.93107 -0.83554 -0.62756 -0.25882 -0.62756 -0.62415 -0.25882 -0.32461 -0.94483 -0.9724
-0.017389 -0.017384 -0.017389 -0.030849 -0.017384 -0.021088 -0.60376 -0.7035 -0.58868 -0.82881 -0.58868 -0.90823 -0.82881 -0.92344 -0.9724 -0.9862 -0.080068 -0.08805 -0.080068 -0.072956 -0.08805 -0.054606 -0.83554 -0.80863
0.1176 0.22047 0.1176 0.22841 0.22047 0.51655 0.78193 0.80863 0.0063677 0.0031259 0.0063677 0.0022607 0.0031259 0.0005913 0.6907 0.7555 0.032413 0.019784 0.032413 0.021067 0.019784 0.0066311 0.72934 0.74238
-0.0025592 -0.0024687 -0.0025592 -0.0044111 -0.0024687 -0.0049399 -0.53342 -0.61588 -0.22608 -0.47106 -0.22608 -0.2105 -0.47106 -0.31295 -0.95861 -0.87627 -0.018379 -0.034498 -0.018379 -0.0097321 -0.034498 -0.010876 -0.64043 -0.6281
0.25621 0.45641 0.25621 0.85936 0.45641 0.92344 0.94483 0.82206 0.0052291 0.01015 0.0052291 0.0043911 0.01015 0.0071281 0.72934 0.74238 0.019585 0.043581 0.019585 0.099656 0.043581 0.10747 0.7555 0.79525
0.089367 0.12415 0.089367 0.15547 0.12415 0.21156 0.86265 0.79525 0.015139 0.022467 0.015139 0.040625 0.022467 0.060937 0.88992 0.90361 0.075427 0.10232 0.075427 0.15181 0.10232 0.13634 0.88992 0.80863
0.28767 0.54809 0.28767 0.63437 0.54809 0.73661 0.83554 0.90361 0.42892 0.14944 0.42892 0.30482 0.14944 0.22965 0.76868 0.82206 0.10759 0.054606 0.10759 0.18137 0.054606 0.19451 0.7555 0.76868
-0.023035 -0.021088 -0.023035 -0.024675 -0.021088 -0.030599 -0.64043 -0.678 -0.54188 -0.68296 -0.54188 -0.58787 -0.68296 -0.86645 -0.95861 -1 -0.11422 -0.14944 -0.11422 -0.11315 -0.14944 -0.08805 -0.76868 -0.7555
0.12879 0.25882 0.12879 0.40946 0.25882 0.88538 0.72934 0.79525 0.0061805 0.0026722 0.0061805 0.0028262 0.0026722 0.00037697 0.678 0.74238 0.030927 0.019784 0.030927 0.011668 0.019784 0.0026722 0.7035 0.76868
-0.0046076 -0.0036488 -0.0046076 -0.0098713 -0.0036488 -0.0071281 -0.57985 -0.5564 -0.23544 -0.54809 -0.23544 -0.1715 -0.54809 -0.26909 -0.90361 -0.83554 -0.02508 -0.046144 -0.02508 -0.015107 -0.046144 -0.01855 -0.66538 -0.64043
0.22754 0.31295 0.22754 0.55559 0.31295 0.64805 0.83554 0.82206 0.017101 0.028795 0.017101 0.019099 0.028795 0.028795 0.82206 0.678 0.039807 0.064324 0.039807 0.10571 0.064324 0.13634 0.78193 0.82206
0.12729 0.2029 0.12729 0.1879 0.2029 0.19451 0.78193 0.94483 0.047016 0.054606 0.047016 0.085432 0.054606 0.08805 0.91733 0.94483 0.069347 0.08805 0.069347 0.081285 0.08805 0.079461 0.82206 0.88992
0.52246 0.94254 0.52246 0.92597 0.94254 0.75479 1 0.91733 0.44798 0.23911 0.44798 0.59156 0.23911 0.54809 0.72934 0.86265 0.36377 0.1785 0.36377 0.64865 0.1785 0.48597 0.82206 0.91733
0.22866 0.26909 0.22866 0.03758 0.26909 0.038814 0.84907 0.87627 -0.83944 -0.56421 -0.83944 -0.99381 -0.56421 -0.51655 -0.95861 -0.9724 0.41968 0.11282 0.41968 0.42102 0.11282 0.071565 0.74238 0.76868
0.054075 0.011648 0.054075 0.062809 0.011648 0.0061655 0.7555 0.71638 0.18997 0.24883 0.18997 0.14701 0.24883 0.16348 0.678 0.71638 0.03271 0.022467 0.03271 0.030781 0.022467 0.015244 0.7035 0.71638
-0.56205 -0.88538 -0.56205 -0.44866 -0.88538 -0.84759 -0.88992 -0.83554 -0.43456 -0.73661 -0.43456 -0.63019 -0.73661 -0.79157 -0.76868 -0.90361 -0.83293 -0.40042 -0.83293 -0.84858 -0.40042 -0.21156 -0.93107 -0.95861
0.00018399 0.00041294 0.00018399 0.00068956 0.00041294 0.00099681 0.61588 0.6281 0.15358 0.014264 0.15358 0.066541 0.014264 0.0033782 0.7035 0.7035 0.016578 0.0013967 0.016578 0.020378 0.0013967 0.0026722 0.6281 0.65286
0.052627 0.032498 0.052627 0.10742 0.032498 0.038814 0.7555 0.7555 0.31241 0.0088259 0.31241 0.13822 0.0088259 0.00099681 0.65286 0.72934 0.10717 0.0082236 0.10717 0.10403 0.0082236 0.001648 0.61588 0.53342
-0.047226 -0.032498 -0.047226 -0.077719 -0.032498 -0.17087 -0.7035 -0.71638 -0.40692 -0.45641 -0.40692 -0.57449 -0.45641 -0.68296 -0.87627 -0.9862 -0.15832 -0.40042 -0.15832 -0.21513 -0.40042 -0.27964 -0.74238 -0.678
0.22866 0.26909 0.22866 0.03758 0.26909 0.038814 0.84907 0.87627 -0.83944 -0.56421 -0.83944 -0.99381 -0.56421 -0.51655 -0.95861 -0.9724 0.41968 0.11282 0.41968 0.42102 0.11282 0.071565 0.74238 0.76868
0.054075 0.011648 0.054075 0.062809 0.011648 0.0061655 0.7555 0.71638 0.18997 0.24883 0.18997 0.14701 0.24883 0.16348 0.678 0.71638 0.03271 0.022467 0.03271 0.030781 0.022467 0.015244 0.7035 0.71638
-0.56205 -0.88538 -0.56205 -0.44866 -0.88538 -0.84759 -0.88992 -0.83554 -0.43456 -0.73661 -0.43456 -0.63019 -0.73661 -0.79157 -0.76868 -0.90361 -0.83293 -0.40042 -0.83293 -0.84858 -0.40042 -0.21156 -0.93107 -0.95861
0.00018399 0.00041294 0.00018399 0.00068956 0.00041294 0.00099681 0.61588 0.6281 0.15358 0.014264 0.15358 0.066541 0.014264 0.0033782 0.7035 0.7035 0.016578 0.0013967 0.016578 0.020378 0.0013967 0.0026722 0.6281 0.65286
0.052627 0.032498 0.052627 0.10742 0.032498 0.038814 0.7555 0.7555 0.31241 0.0088259 0.31241 0.13822 0.0088259 0.00099681 0.65286 0.72934 0.10717 0.0082236 0.10717 0.10403 0.0082236 0.001648 0.61588 0.53342
-0.047226 -0.032498 -0.047226 -0.077719 -0.032498 -0.17087 -0.7035 -0.71638 -0.40692 -0.45641 -0.40692 -0.57449 -0.45641 -0.68296 -0.87627 -0.9862 -0.15832 -0.40042 -0.15832 -0.21513 -0.40042 -0.27964 -0.74238 -0.678
-0.72515 -0.88538 -0.72515 -0.50653 -0.88538 -0.86645 -0.9862 -0.93107 -0.45307 -0.51655 -0.45307 -0.43878 -0.51655 -0.47106 -1 -0.9724 -0.54025 -0.94254 -0.54025 -0.38445 -0.94254 -0.40042 -0.9724 -0.90361
0.12293 0.42788 0.12293 0.18165 0.42788 0.38709 0.7555 0.84907 0.073486 0.034498 0.073486 0.065957 0.034498 0.16348 0.80863 0.86265 0.084916 0.083666 0.084916 0.08096 0.083666 0.097373 0.78193 0.74238
-0.40514 -0.54809 -0.40514 -0.31293 -0.54809 -0.45641 -0.83554 -0.80863 -0.22402 -0.12415 -0.22402 -0.17572 -0.12415 -0.071565 -0.93107 -0.82206 -0.32081 -0.5322 -0.32081 -0.28703 -0.5322 -0.38709 -0.82206 -0.84907
0.34664 0.21156 0.34664 0.38706 0.21156 0.29047 0.78193 0.7035 0.26534 0.08805 0.26534 0.26836 0.08805 0.1785 0.74238 0.74238 0.21004 0.18638 0.21004 0.23408 0.18638 0.22965 0.76868 0.74238
0.38792 0.13634 0.38792 0.27878 0.13634 0.23911 0.87627 0.95861 -0.74083 -0.50114 -0.74083 -0.6596 -0.50114 -0.27964 -0.9862 -0.9862 0.83816 0.22965 0.83816 0.72337 0.22965 0.2029 0.88992 0.94483
-0.44075 -0.45641 -0.44075 -0.7792 -0.45641 -0.77312 -0.9862 -0.94483 -0.22813 -0.27964 -0.22813 -0.43782 -0.27964 -0.45641 -0.91733 -0.93107 -0.045648 -0.046144 -0.045648 -0.26919 -0.046144 -0.27964 -0.83554 -0.86265
-0.72515 -0.88538 -0.72515 -0.50653 -0.88538 -0.86645 -0.9862 -0.93107 -0.45307 -0.51655 -0.45307 -0.43878 -0.51655 -0.47106 -1 -0.9724 -0.54025 -0.94254 -0.54025 -0.38445 -0.94254 -0.40042 -0.9724 -0.90361
0.12293 0.42788 0.12293 0.18165 0.42788 0.38709 0.7555 0.84907 0.073486 0.034498 0.073486 0.065957 0.034498 0.16348 0.80863 0.86265 0.084916 0.083666 0.084916 0.08096 0.083666 0.097373 0.78193 0.74238
-0.40514 -0.54809 -0.40514 -0.31293 -0.54809 -0.45641 -0.83554 -0.80863 -0.22402 -0.12415 -0.22402 -0.17572 -0.12415 -0.071565 -0.93107 -0.82206 -0.32081 -0.5322 -0.32081 -0.28703 -0.5322 -0.38709 -0.82206 -0.84907
0.34664 0.21156 0.34664 0.38706 0.21156 0.29047 0.78193 0.7035 0.26534 0.08805 0.26534 0.26836 0.08805 0.1785 0.74238 0.74238 0.21004 0.18638 0.21004 0.23408 0.18638 0.22965 0.76868 0.74238
0.38792 0.13634 0.38792 0.27878 0.13634 0.23911 0.87627 0.95861 -0.74083 -0.50114 -0.74083 -0.6596 -0.50114 -0.27964 -0.9862 -0.9862 0.83816 0.22965 0.83816 0.72337 0.22965 0.2029 0.88992 0.94483
-0.44075 -0.45641 -0.44075 -0.7792 -0.45641 -0.77312 -0.9862 -0.94483 -0.22813 -0.27964 -0.22813 -0.43782 -0.27964 -0.45641 -0.91733 -0.93107 -0.045648 -0.046144 -0.045648 -0.26919 -0.046144 -0.27964 -0.83554 -0.86265
-0.30393 -0.61389 -0.30393 -0.3249 -0.61389 -0.71857 -0.95861 -0.84907 -0.30393 -0.61389 -0.30393 -0.3249 -0.61389 -0.71857 -0.95861 -0.84907 -0.30393 -0.61389 -0.30393 -0.3249 -0.61389 -0.71857 -0.95861 -0.84907
0.067557 0.15634 0.067557 0.10537 0.15634 0.16348 0.74238 0.72934 0.067557 0.15634 0.067557 0.10537 0.15634 0.16348 0.74238 0.72934 0.067557 0.15634 0.067557 0.10537 0.15634 0.16348 0.74238 0.72934
-0.15777 -0.24883 -0.15777 -0.096146 -0.24883 -0.15634 -0.71638 -0.74238 -0.15777 -0.24883 -0.15777 -0.096146 -0.24883 -0.15634 -0.71638 -0.74238 -0.15777 -0.24883 -0.15777 -0.096146 -0.24883 -0.15634 -0.71638 -0.74238
0.50977 0.40042 0.50977 0.9036 0.40042 0.68296 0.93107 0.94483 0.50977 0.40042 0.50977 0.9036 0.40042 0.68296 0.93107 0.94483 0.50977 0.40042 0.50977 0.9036 0.40042 0.68296 0.93107 0.94483
0.63423 0.32461 0.63423 0.89161 0.32461 0.34877 0.9862 0.9724 0.63423 0.32461 0.63423 0.89161 0.32461 0.34877 0.9862 0.9724 0.63423 0.32461 0.63423 0.89161 0.32461 0.34877 0.9862 0.9724
0.045337 0.057699 0.045337 0.11088 0.057699 0.097373 0.71638 0.66538 0.045337 0.057699 0.045337 0.11088 0.057699 0.097373 0.71638 0.66538 0.045337 0.057699 0.045337 0.11088 0.057699 0.097373 0.71638 0.66538
-0.46426 -0.81014 -0.46426 -0.3263 -0.81014 -0.71857 -0.9862 -0.87627 -0.46426 -0.81014 -0.46426 -0.3263 -0.81014 -0.71857 -0.9862 -0.87627 -0.46426 -0.81014 -0.46426 -0.3263 -0.81014 -0.71857 -0.9862 -0.87627
0.09506 0.10747 0.09506 0.18382 0.10747 0.26909 0.80863 0.78193 0.09506 0.10747 0.09506 0.18382 0.10747 0.26909 0.80863 0.78193 0.09506 0.10747 0.09506 0.18382 0.10747 0.26909 0.80863 0.78193
-0.24276 -0.37404 -0.24276 -0.13936 -0.37404 -0.25882 -0.7555 -0.82206 -0.24276 -0.37404 -0.24276 -0.13936 -0.37404 -0.25882 -0.7555 -0.82206 -0.24276 -0.37404 -0.24276 -0.13936 -0.37404 -0.25882 -0.7555 -0.82206
0.61827 0.50114 0.61827 0.9529 0.50114 0.68296 0.84907 0.95861 0.61827 0.50114 0.61827 0.9529 0.50114 0.68296 0.84907 0.95861 0.61827 0.50114 0.61827 0.9529 0.50114 0.68296 0.84907 0.95861
0.76173 0.36127 0.76173 0.84912 0.36127 0.63087 0.94483 0.9724 0.76173 0.36127 0.76173 0.84912 0.36127 0.63087 0.94483 0.9724 0.76173 0.36127 0.76173 0.84912 0.36127 0.63087 0.94483 0.9724
0.10662 0.11282 0.10662 0.1954 0.11282 0.1785 0.80863 0.66538 0.10662 0.11282 0.10662 0.1954 0.11282 0.1785 0.80863 0.66538 0.10662 0.11282 0.10662 0.1954 0.11282 0.1785 0.80863 0.66538
-0.18402 -0.37404 -0.18402 -0.20787 -0.37404 -0.51655 -0.79525 -0.78193 -0.18402 -0.37404 -0.18402 -0.20787 -0.37404 -0.51655 -0.79525 -0.78193 -0.18402 -0.37404 -0.18402 -0.20787 -0.37404 -0.51655 -0.79525 -0.78193
0.096437 0.26909 0.096437 0.1764 0.26909 0.50114 0.87627 0.84907 0.096437 0.26909 0.096437 0.1764 0.26909 0.50114 0.87627 0.84907 0.096437 0.26909 0.096437 0.1764 0.26909 0.50114 0.87627 0.84907
-0.07925 -0.11282 -0.07925 -0.081046 -0.11282 -0.08805 -0.678 -0.72934 -0.07925 -0.11282 -0.07925 -0.081046 -0.11282 -0.08805 -0.678 -0.72934 -0.07925 -0.11282 -0.07925 -0.081046 -0.11282 -0.08805 -0.678 -0.72934
0.69474 0.56421 0.69474 0.9356 0.56421 0.94254 0.95861 0.94483 0.69474 0.56421 0.69474 0.9356 0.56421 0.94254 0.95861 0.94483 0.69474 0.56421 0.69474 0.9356 0.56421 0.94254 0.95861 0.94483
0.8479 0.58055 0.8479 0.87145 0.58055 0.86645 0.94483 0.94483 0.8479 0.58055 0.8479 0.87145 0.58055 0.86645 0.94483 0.94483 0.8479 0.58055 0.8479 0.87145 0.58055 0.86645 0.94483 0.94483
0.16933 0.097373 0.16933 0.14472 0.097373 0.19451 0.7555 0.74238 0.16933 0.097373 0.16933 0.14472 0.097373 0.19451 0.7555 0.74238 0.16933 0.097373 0.16933 0.14472 0.097373 0.19451 0.7555 0.74238
-0.22899 -0.40042 -0.22899 -0.17622 -0.40042 -0.44201 -0.84907 -0.79525 -0.22899 -0.40042 -0.22899 -0.17622 -0.40042 -0.44201 -0.84907 -0.79525 -0.22899 -0.40042 -0.22899 -0.17622 -0.40042 -0.44201 -0.84907 -0.79525
0.10613 0.23911 0.10613 0.2043 0.23911 0.56421 0.90361 0.91733 0.10613 0.23911 0.10613 0.2043 0.23911 0.56421 0.90361 0.91733 0.10613 0.23911 0.10613 0.2043 0.23911 0.56421 0.90361 0.91733
-0.13336 -0.13634 -0.13336 -0.11589 -0.13634 -0.21156 -0.678 -0.7555 -0.13336 -0.13634 -0.13336 -0.11589 -0.13634 -0.21156 -0.678 -0.7555 -0.13336 -0.13634 -0.13336 -0.11589 -0.13634 -0.21156 -0.678 -0.7555
0.76158 0.63087 0.76158 0.95729 0.63087 0.88538 0.94483 0.95861 0.76158 0.63087 0.76158 0.95729 0.63087 0.88538 0.94483 0.95861 0.76158 0.63087 0.76158 0.95729 0.63087 0.88538 0.94483 0.95861
0.9543 0.59712 0.9543 0.90589 0.59712 0.73661 0.91733 0.90361 0.9543 0.59712 0.9543 0.90589 0.59712 0.73661 0.91733 0.90361 0.9543 0.59712 0.9543 0.90589 0.59712 0.73661 0.91733 0.90361
0.17172 0.13013 0.17172 0.18496 0.13013 0.19451 0.678 0.74238 0.17172 0.13013 0.17172 0.18496 0.13013 0.19451 0.678 0.74238 0.17172 0.13013 0.17172 0.18496 0.13013 0.19451 0.678 0.74238
}

%\pgfmathparse{int(less(abs(#1),0.05)}% + 2*int(greater(#1,0)) + 1*int(less(#1,0)) }


\end{document}
```